# What is the difference between Bound Service and Foreground Service?

Tags: java, android, service, difference, foreground

I was trying to create a service that can interact with the AppUI when the App is opened and continues its working when the App is closed.

I have heard that the `bindService()` call creates a Bound Service that can communicate with the App. At the same time, Some resources say that the `startService()` can be further made a Foreground Service by calling `startForeground()` inside the `onStartCommand()` callback, and then use them to communicate with the App.

Can anyone give the best way to achieve my need and the difference between this?

Answer (score 3):

From the Official Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

**Bound**

> A service is bound when an application component binds to it by
>   calling bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server
>   interface that allows components to interact with the service, send
>   requests, receive results, and even do so across processes with
>   interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service runs only as long as
>   another application component is bound to it. Multiple components can
>   bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service
>   is destroyed.

**Foreground**

> A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the
>   user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play
>   an audio track. Foreground services must display a status bar icon.
>   **Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't
>   interacting with the app**.

It looks like you should use Foreground Service.